# Highcharts Heatmap by Column

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I'm creating a heatmap from highcharts that shows the allocation to different asset classes for multiple portfolios.  The y-axis contains asset classes and the x-axis contains the portfolios (1 - 20).

The heatmap I've constructed looks very much like the one in this demo:  https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap.  What I would like to do is to essentially construct a heatmap per column (or per portfolio).  Is this possible with highcharts?

I'm using the code below to construct the heatmap currently:

```
  Highcharts.chart('portfolioChart', {
    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      height: 700
    },
    title: {
      text: 'After-tax Portfolio Composition'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: json.columns,
      align: 'top'
    },
    yAxis: {
      categories: json.index,
      title: null,
      reversed: true
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      minColor: '#fff',
      maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      layout: 'vertical',
      margin: 0,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 25,
      symbolHeight: 600
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ', ' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b> = ' + (this.point.value*100).toFixed(1) + '%'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Portfolio Allocation',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: portfolioData,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000',
        formatter: function() {
          return (this.point.value * 100).toFixed(1) + '%';
        }
      }
    }]
  });
```

Comment: What would a heatmap per column look like to you? Wouldn't that just be the heatmap as it is now? You could try a percent stacked bar chart where the columns represent portfolios.

Comment: You're right.  Initially, I was thinking about Tableau and how they have functionality where you can say compute using the table-down (columns) or the table-across (rows).  I played around with it for a little bit and it's essentially the result that highcharts gives me.  Thanks for taking the time.